# Find files between a certain alpha range

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
string startAlpha = "A";
string StartSubAlpha = "a-e";
var currentPage = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, startAlpha + "*.pdf")
                           .Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize)
                           .Take(pageSize)
                           .Select(path => new FileInfo(path)).ToArray();
```

This works when only using startAlpha. But how can I integrate StartSubAlpha into it? I want to be able to find all files that has a starting letters (first 2) between `"Aa-Ae"` (from the example above).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well why not just follow the answer you accepted from your earlier question? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653201)

Comment: You will have to revert to using "external" regular expression to filter the results. The search pattern for GetFiles simply does not support what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Directory.GetFiles with a regex in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443524/using-directory-getfiles-with-a-regex-in-c)

Comment: Yes - sorry. I was a bit fast on the keyboard there. Actually the question should have been about the regex - @enzi helped me out below. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653201/directory-getfiles-show-only-files-starting-with-a-numeric-value).

The regex you're looking for could be formulated as `A[a-e].*`

Comment: Thanks - i was a bit fast in my initial distriction of my issue, it was just the regex i was looking for. Your's work