# c# how to write Regular Expression filter

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to filter files in directory in C#.

I think Regex is the best way, but I'm in troubles writing the expression... someone can help me...

Here my code:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(Expr);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Dir, "*.txt")
               .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path))
               .ToList();
```

My Expression Expr would match all files that start with "fileXXX" and don't end with "_L.txt", how can I solve my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Here is a [similar one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653201/directory-getfiles-show-only-files-starting-with-a-numeric-value). Your `path` contains the file path, not just the file name.

Comment: What is `XXX`? 3 digits? If that is a literal, you just do not need a regex here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `fileXXX` is a literal, you can achieve what you need with a mere `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`:

```
var files = Directory
   .EnumerateFiles(Dir, "*.txt")
   .Where(path => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path).StartsWith("fileXXX") 
               && !Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path).EndsWith("_L"))
   .ToList();
```

Note that your `path` contains the *file path* including the folder path, not just the file name. That is why you need to use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)` to perform the check on.

Else, use a regex like

```
var files1 = Directory
   .GetFiles(Dir, "*.txt")
   .Where(path => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path), @"^fileXXX.*(?<!_L)$"))
   .ToList();
```

Where `^fileXXX.*(?<!_L)$` matches any text (here, a file name without extension) that starts with `fileXXX` and does not end with `_L` (due to the negative lookbehind `(?<!_L)` before an end of string anchor `$`).