# Return file name which has the highest value

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a .NET Framework (C#) app. 
I have a directory which contains files and folders. Each folder has a 3 digit number as its name. I want to find the folder name which has the highest value.

So far, I came up with the following code:

```
public void doCopyFiles()
{
    string sourceDir = @"C:\Users\xyz\abc\gth";
    var sorted = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, ".").OrderBy(path => int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)));
    var lastFile = sorted.Last();
    Console.WriteLine(lastFile);
}
```

However, this throws a System.FormatException, which says "input string not in expected format". I am assuming this is because there are other files present which have normal strings as their filename.

Are there any suggestions on how to fix this?

EDIT: After trying both solutions shown below, the same error is still persisting.

Comment: If the issue is the non-numeric "other files", then consider this answer which uses RegEx to only grab the numeric file names.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653201/directory-getfiles-show-only-files-starting-with-a-numeric-value

Comment: @BryanLewis turns out that might not be the problem, I am not sure what else it could be

Comment: Can you see the file name that is causing the error?

Comment: Which line is it throwing the exception on?  GetFiles()?

Comment: I can't see which filename was throwing the error. The exception was being thrown by the GetFiles()

Comment: That exception message is definitely coming from int.Parse().  So at least one of the filenames is not valid to pass into Parse (non-numeric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to reflect answers to comment question and suggestion.

```
  public void doCopyFiles()
  {
      int highestFolder = int.MinValue;

      string sourceDir = @"C:\Users\xyz\abc\gth";

      var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir);
      foreach(var value in dirs)
      {

           if(int.TryParse(value, out int result))
           {
                if(result > highestFolder)
                {
                     highestFolder = result;
                }
           }

      }

      if(highestFolder != int.MinValue)
      {
           Console.WriteLine(highestFolder);
      }
      else //no folder with int names were found
      {
           //error message
      }
   }
```

Comment: Suggestion: instead of a filling a list, sorting it and throwing away almost all, keep a single number that is the highest value so far. Maybe also keep the filename that belongs to that number

Answer (score 0):

The fix for your implementation would be to first select the file names that are all numerals. This can be done by checking for a match with the regex `\d+`

```
var sorted = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, ".")
    .Where(  path => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path), @"\d+"))
    .OrderBy(path => int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)));
```

Assuming your numeric file names are zero padded (001 instead of 1), you can sort without parsing the value. Based on the numeric values of the ASCII characters, your numbered files should be listed in order and first in the sorted list.